# How can I convert String into array of characters in java

Tags: java, arrays

```
import java.util.*;

public class prac9 
{
    public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner scn=new Scanner(System.in);

    int count=0;
    String x,str=" ";

    System.out.println("Regular Expression is (a+b)(ab+ba)*");
    System.out.println("Enter a Word: ");
    x=scn.nextLine();  //here simple x string type of varible

    if(x[0]=="a"|| x[0]=="b")  //here x array of string type of varible
    {                          //prac9.java:15: error: array 
                             // required,but String found


         for(int i=1; i<x.length(); i++)
         {
             str+=x[i];  
             if((i%2==0)==true)
             {
                 if(str=="ab" || str=="ba")
                 {
                     count=count+2;
                     str=" ";
                 }
             }

         }
         if((count+1)==(x.length())){
             System.out.println("Acceptable"); 
         }
         else{
             System.out.println("Not Acceptable");
         }

    }
    else{ 
        System.out.println("Not Acceptable..");
    }
}
```

Please help me as simply as possible. It gives me an error as I mentioned in above comment. I know what it is saying, but I can't figure out how to convert a String into an array so I can check every single character given by a user.
Actually, this code was written in C++. I just converted it into Java language.

Comment: You should create a array or You can use charAt(index) like `x.charAt(0)=='a'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the first character of the string using [`charAt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt-int-) as follows -

```
x.charAt(0) == 'a'
```

since that would return the first character of the string (based of start index = 0)

Answer (score 3):

```
if(x[0]=="a"|| x[0]=="b")
```

can be changed to:

```
if(x.startsWith("a") || x.startsWith("b"))
```

and

```
str+=x[i];
```

can be changed to:

```
str+=x.charAt(i);
```

and lastly:

```
 if(str=="ab" || str=="ba")
```

should be changed to

```
 if(str.equals("ab") || str.equals("ba"))
```

Comment: the way u explained it to me is far far better than my classmates.i appreciate your effort bro.

Comment: I have edited my code as you said but this condition,if(str.equals("ab") || str.equals("ba")) , is not satisfying my word aab,aba,bab,bba which is bye the way correct word for given regular expression. now it's a logical mistake.because at str variable after 2nd iteration .equal() method compared with only single character in str. i want compare the double character with ab or ba. how am i gonna write this logic.@pleft.thanks for help.

Comment: Sorry but I do not understand your comment above. One thing that I realized is that you initialize variable `str` as `str = " "`, that means that `str` is not empty but contains a "space" character. So when you reach the if statement `if(str.equals("ab") || str.equals("ba"))` it never succeeds because the `str` variable actually is `" ab"` instead of `"ab"`.

Comment: I think you perfectly got it. now it's working and accepting the accepted words like aabab,bababa.ababab for given regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

`x` is a String, you'd need to convert it to an array of chars, then compare each char with `'a'` and `'b'`. To do that replace this line of code `if(x[0]=="a"|| x[0]=="b")` by

```
char[] x_chars = x.toCharArray();
if (x_chars[0] == 'a' || x_chars[0] == 'b') {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If one checks the documentation

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html
you can find the method

```
x.charAt(0)
```

which is used in java instead of x[0].

Answer (score 1):

Your "x" variable is of String type, not an array. To declare "x" as string array, you should use

```
String x[] = new String[n];  //here 'n' is number of elements you store in your 'x' array
```

Also if you don't know how many elements can be are to be included in array, that can also grow and shrink based on your requirement you can use "ArrayList " like this;

```
ArrayList<String> al=new ArrayList<String>();  
al.add("J"); //add 'J' as 1st element of 'al'
al.add("a");
al.add("v");
al.add("a");
System.out.println("element at 2nd position: "+al.get(2));  //get 'a'
al.remove(0)  //to remove 'J'
.............
```